# Как получить данные из формы на админку , т.е на определенный игфоблок(Битрикс)

Tags: битрикс

У меня есть форма заявки и некоторый инфоблок.

Когда клиент заполняет форму, то её данные сохраняются в результатах формы.

Как сделать так, чтобы эти же данные сохранялись и в моём инфоблоке?

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более понятным языком. Переписал вопрос, чтобы более понятно.

Comment: Из коробки битрикс сохраняет формы в формы. Чтобы сохранить ещё и в инфоблок - вам нужно будет писать дополнительный код, чтобы сохранить ещё и в инфоблок. Как-то так: [CIBlockElement::Add](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/add.php) (пример внутри)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/akbarsulaymonov/33197f36d4c96a5de80da811bc625e0e

Comment: проходите по ссылке , я сделал...  правильно ли это?

Comment: Сделайте форму на инфоблоке, а не через "Сервис"-"Формы".

Answer (score 0):

Форму в Битриксе можно создать одним из двух способов. Либо через "Сервис" - "Формы", тогда результаты будут в "Результатах формы" там же.

Или же можно создать через инфоблоки. Для этого под Вашу форму создаете инфоблок. Его свойства должны быть полями формы. В публичной части на необходимой странице подключаете компонент "Редактирование элеметна инфоблока" и указываете нужный инфоблок и остальные настройки. Совместить штатным образом не получится, тут нужна доработка.

Определитесь как Вам лучше хранить и видеть результаты и выбирайте удобный вариант. Конечно можно и создать форму через "Сервис"-"Формы", а результат дублировать в нужный инфоблок, но для этого требуется доработка функционала.